# MS-Teams , trying to send images (present on local machine) to Teams Channel webhook url

Tags: powershell, webhooks, microsoft-teams

**I'm trying to send images (present on local machine) to Teams Channel webhook url.**

Is this supported in any type of card that is available ?

I see references on how to send images that is present  on other websites, but how to send images that is present on local machine ?

If this is not supported , can someone guide me how to upload image to azure blob container and how to post that image to teams using powershell

Answer (score 5):

This is absolutely possible if you convert the image to a base64 format, e.g. using the [Base64 Image Encoder](https://www.base64-image.de) or any local equivalent.

I saved [this example image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Example_images#/media/File:Information_example_page2_300px.jpg) from Wikimedia Commons to my computer, and converted the image to base64 in R using `base64enc::base64encode()`. I'm sure there are also PowerShell methods.

Then just POST your call:

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "text": "Wikimedia Commons example",
    "sections": [
        {
            "images": [
                {
                    "image": "data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QDkRXhpZgAASUkqAD4AAAAEAAGgAwABAAAA//8AAAKgBAABAAAALAEAAAOgBAABAAAAyAAAAAWgBAABAAAACAAAAAAAAAAHABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBCgABAAAA1AAAABsBCgABAAAAzAAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAdAAAArgAAADIBAgAVAAAAmAAAAGmHBAABAAAACAAAANwAAAAyMDA4OjAzOjEwIDIzOjQ3OjI3AP//QWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTMiBXaW5kb3dzAP//gPwKABAnAACA/AoAECcAAP/iA6BJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAA5BBREJFAhAAAHBydHJHUkFZWFlaIAfPAAYAAwAAAAAAAGFjc3BBUFBMAAAAAG5vbmUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD21gABAAAAANMtQURCRQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABWNwcnQAAADAAAAAMmRlc2MAAAD0AAAAZ3d0cHQAAAFcAAAAFGJrcHQAAAFwAAAAFGtUUkMAAAGEAAACDHRleHQAAAAAQ29weXJpZ2h0IDE5OTkgQWRvYmUgU3lzdGVtcyBJbmNvcnBvcmF0ZWQAAABkZXNjAAAAAAAAAA1Eb3QgR2FpbiAxNSUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFhZWiAAAAAAAAD21gABAAAAANMtWFlaIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABjdXJ2AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAQACoATgB5AKoA4AEbAVoBngHlAjECgALSAygDgQPdBDwEngUDBWsF1QZCBrIHJAeZCBAIiQkFCYMKAwqGCwsLkQwaDKUNMw3CDlMO5g97EBIQqxFGEeISgRMhE8MUZxUNFbUWXhcJF7UYZBkTGcUaeBstG+QcnB1VHhEezR+MIEwhDSHQIpQjWiQiJOsltSaBJ04oHSjtKb4qkStlLDstEi3qLsQvnzB8MVoyOTMZM/s03jXDNqg3jzh4OWE6TDs4PCU9FD4EPvU/50DbQdBCxkO9RLVFr0apR6VIokmhSqBLoUyjTaZOqk+vULVRvVLGU89U2lXmVvRYAlkRWiJbM1xGXVpebl+EYJths2LNY+dlAmYeZzxoWml6apprvGzebgJvJ3BMcXNym3PDdO12GHdEeHF5nnrNe/19Ln5ff5KAxoH7gzCEZ4WehteIEYlLioeLw40Ajj+PfpC+kf+TQZSFlciXDZhTmZqa4pwqnXSevqAKoVaio6PxpUCmkKfhqTOqhavZrS2ugq/ZsTCyiLPgtTq2lbfwuU26qrwIvWe+x8AnwYnC68ROxbPHF8h9yeTLS8y0zh3Ph9Dy0l7TytU41qbYFdmF2vXcZ93Z30zgwOI146vlIeaZ6BHpiusD7H7t+e918PLycPPu9W727vhv+fD7c/z2/nr////bAEMAAwICAwICAwMDAwQDAwQFCAUFBAQFCgcHBggMCgwMCwoLCw0OEhANDhEOCwsQFhARExQVFRUMDxcYFhQYEhQVFP/AAAsIAMgBLAEBEQD/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAAAX0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/2gAIAQEAAD8A/Kqiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiip7Wwur0Sm3tpbgRKXkMSFtijqTjoPehLC6kk2LbTM+AdoQk4OMHHvkfnW2vw48VveXFoPDWrC6t4hPNAbKQPHGRuDEEZAIOc+nPSui8Kfs8/EnxvqK2Oi+DNYvrho0n2paPxGzbQ/T7ueCe1e0xf8ExPj9c+FIdbh8JB2YTF9Pa4RLmMxnGCjEZ3c4xnOPpnI+H//AATr+O3xA1BLaPwVd6OjBj9o1b/R0G3AOd3PVl/AkjODXqPif/gkL8Z9MGnNpI07VVuNPFzOv2lY2t7gfegOep9COMnGeM1kWX/BJn48TeIbSyuNJsYNPlljWTUPtiFIkbGWKg7vlB5AHUHrT7f/AIJJ/Hmb+11fTtNiezQvb7r1Nt5hsbUI6Ej5hux9Qa9F8D/8EX/iDqN2r+JfE2k6ZYy2hdfsxaSaKYoSquuAMBsA4b1xmuj+Hn/BFXXpL7UE8aeMbGCza2YWkukq0jpNxtLKwUFfXn8uo5i7/wCCK3xMjnlW38X+HpYgxEcjmVSy54JG0447UW//AARY+JXnx+d4s0Dydw37Hk3bc84+TrV7xH/wRU8dx63eLonjHRp9K8wm3kuxIkpT/aUAgEdOvarFl/wRP8YyW9wbrxzpUM/2ZXhEcTuvn7sMjcD5SuSGHfgjvV/S/wDgil4hPh3xCmoeNdPXWlZDpEkMbmGQBjuEwIyuV9M4OPQ580/aE/4JK/Ej4W+H7DWfBsv/AAnsXkA6jY2key5tpMclFJ/ep7j5uPu18U+IvBuu+EZIY9b0e90p5lLxreQNEWAJUkZHYgg+4rHooooooq/pGgan4gu0tdL0671G6fhIbSFpXb6BQSa7jXP2cfid4csdGvNR8Da3bW2sRedYyGzcidcE8YHXAztPJGCBgisuD4MeOrrSLbU4fCery2VzcPaxSpaOQ8qKGZBx1wQcd67rwD+xj8YPiJ/YU+m+CNVGl6xL5UGovARCuGALMf4QM98Dr6HHovhb/gmF8ePEni2+0WTw0mlx2N4trPqF5MFg2k8TRn/lomBn5cn2r0LxP/wRw+Mmiaelxp+p6Frkvmqj21tM0bqhPLjeADjuM5q74D/4I2/FXXoZpfEWr6T4eaOSSMQmQzM+0jaylQRtYZwTgjuK9tX/AIIkaCTf7viJdgOyta4sR+6HG5W+b5h97B4PT3zr6H/wRY8Gafr0V3feNNQvrBJYpPsZtlXcAR5iFsnIPOOOOM55zN4p/wCCLPgTU/F019o3jDU9I0KVt39mvCszxZzkJJkcDjGQffNdNY/8Ebvg3HYwpd6p4gmuhGolljuEVWfA3FQVOATk4ya6zw1/wSg+Bfh+1MM1hqOqsLuG7WW8ufmXyycx/KBlGBwQfwxUEX/BJb4Ew2Wp2ws9Ub7XdR3MUjXWWtghY+WnHKkNg5yeBzXufwU/ZQ+GnwE8NyaP4Y8OWxjl81Zbq9RZ55Y5GyY2dhkrwBjpx65rpYfgV8OreSOSPwPoCSRwm3Rl0+IERnPy/d6cnj3rrxpVkshcWduHK7C3lLkrjGM46YqWK0ggIMUMcZA2gogGB1xU1FFFFFFFFFFFFcv41+F/hH4jaeLLxP4b0vXrUbtsd/apKF3AhsZHGcnpX5T/AB4/4I4eKNO8d2b/AAv1WHUfCuo3RWSLVH2TaUpbjcf+WqAHqPm45B618H/GP4K+MPgL41uvC3jXR5tI1SHLIXGYriPcQJYn6OhwcEfjg8Vw9ABJwOTX3f8As1f8EqfEvxv0m18Qav4q0/SPDN3YieC606RLyQzlsGIhW2jbhsnP931OPq/wX/wRa+E2lQ2kniPxP4o167jbM8cE8NtbSjJwAoiLgYx/H2Prx7r4b/4Jv/s4+FL+G9sPhnaNcxEFHu9QvLkA+u2WZl/SvoTTvDmk6Ra29tY6ZZ2dvbqEhiggVFjUdAoA4A9quNbQuqK0SMqEFQVGFI6Y9KYthbIoVbeJVDbwAgwG9frUsUSQIEjRY0HRVGAKfRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRX5G/8Fvfsy+N/hgFiH2trC8LS7znYJI8Lt6Dksc9/wAK/Mmiv2T/AOCKnimTUfgh4z0J7qN00zWVmS3VG3xiaIfMzHghvLwFHTYT/FX6K0UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUV+Kv8AwWM+LWm+M/jzo3g+wjikuPCliUvrtQN5mn2yCHPoiBD9ZDnpXwDRX7Wf8EafBGu+Gf2cdc1fU7SO003Xtae600mLbNNGkaxNIzd0LIQo/wBlj/FX35RRRRRRXw/8Qf8Agrn8Hvht4+8S+EdT8N+N59S0DU7nSrqW0sbNoXlglaJyha7UlSyEgkA4xkDpWB/w+r+CH/QrfED/AMF1j/8AJlevfBT/AIKE/Dr47+Afid4u0HRfFFppvw+0watqkWpWtsk00RiuJdsAS4cM221k4coMleeSR0H7Kf7avgj9sA+KP+EN0rxBpv8Awjv2X7X/AG5bwRb/ALR52zy/KmkzjyHznGMrjPOPoGvl79p//goV8Ov2TfH9h4R8XaL4o1HUr3TI9Vjl0W1t5YRE8ssQBMtxGd2YHOACMFeeoH1DRRRXy94H/wCChPw68fftLXPwQ07RfFEPiy31PUNKa8ubW2WxMtmszSsHW4L7SLd9p2ZOVyBk4+oaKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/Bz/grD4RsfC37YetzWW8Pq9hbajcBiMCVgyHaABgYjU85OcnPNfHVe3fsXfBXRP2gv2kPCXgjxFdT2uj30kstwLbiSZYomlMQb+HdswW6gE45xX9FPh3w/p/hTQdP0bSbOHT9LsIEtrW0t0CRwxqAFVQOgAAFaNFFFFFFeZar+zL8H9f1a81PVPhR4I1HUr2Z7m6vLvw5ZyzTyuxZ5HdoyWZmJJYkkknNfkH/wAEjPh74W+JP7SPiTTPF3hrR/FWmxeE7m5js9asIryFJReWaiQJKrAMFdhuxnDMO5r9R/jt8J/BHwv/AGWvjj/whvg7w/4SF94M1X7X/YWlwWX2jZY3GzzPKVd+3e+M5xubHU1+VP8AwT1/akv/ANnLQPifZeF/Buo+PvH3iV9Lj0bQ9Pt5ZdywLeGaaQRKzFUEkfyqMtu6gAkfXP7Jn/BU3xD8TvjZZfDT4qeD9P8ADWqandNYWt3pkc0H2a7GdsE8EzuwLMNmQQQ20FcEkc//AMFPv2m/+FL/AB90DRP+FT/DDx35/hm3vf7S8a+HP7RvI911dJ5SSeYuIh5e4Ljhnc554+sv21/2x9J/Y88Aadqs+lNr/iDWZpLbStLE3lI5RQZJZHwcIm5MgAkl1HGSw+TNS/4KAftaeGPh5pPxM1n4J+Gh8OtUML2t3AsxmkjmI8okLdO6B8qFdogCWXGcgH7x/Zz+ND/H74U6X4vm8Mat4OvLgtFc6RrEDxyQyLjOxmVfMjOQVkAAIOCAQQPT6/MD4H/tN/8ACS/8FLNR+H3/AAqf4YaV5fibxDZ/8JVpnhzydcfyI7w+abrzDmWTy8SNt+YO/Azx65+2V/wUWv8A4FfFSw+FPw78Jw+MPH9ybdJBeu4ghmuMeRbrGhDSSOHQ/eUAOvJJIXzm/wD+Cgv7S3wW+IOh6F8YPgTYtDqqGaG28LCV7mSEEB2iZJ7hHZdwyh2nlQSuQa/RrRtUj13SbHUYY7iCG7gjuEjuoWhmRXUMA8bAMjAHBUgEHII4pNc1qx8N6JqGr6ncpZ6bYW8l3dXEpwsUSKXdz7BQT+Ffl7rX/BV/4xfErxPrCfBH4NDxB4f09vmmudMvdTuBHk7ZJVtnRYd2CdpLY/vHFeu/sNf8FLbr9pT4iP8ADzxr4XtfD3imSCWeyudMaQW9w0Q3SRNFIS8bhQzA7mBCtnBAzzX7Qv8AwU/8Sfs7ftgeJfh/rHh7SNR+H2ixRsXtIJRqs0kmmJcRoJTN5Sg3EiKT5ZwmeCRk+W67/wAFdvjb4K1zS9R8TfBzTdF8J6mPtFlbX9re2txdwcfNFcudjjDL86xEcjjmv04+DvxS0j42fDHw3450EyLpeuWaXUUcwHmRE8PG2ONyuGU4JGVOK7Siiiiiivw3/wCCwiWy/tc5hlLztoVoZ1wcI26TAyf9nB445HfNfD9e9fsH+I7zwz+158Lbizu3snuNahspJEQMWjmPlunPZgxUnsGJr+i6iiiiiiiivxW/4Iqf8nT+Kf8AsTLr/wBLrGv1U/ax/wCTWPjJ/wBiZrP/AKQzV+eP/BDnRbOfXPjBq8kCNf2tvpVrDMR8yRytdNIoPYEwxkjvtHpXm37RMEdj/wAFjdKSBREreNfC7kLxkvHYMx/EsT+NP/4LV/8AJ03hb/sTLX/0uvq+/wD9v39i+X9sHwFokGkatb6P4r8PTzTadLfBjbTJKqCWKQqCyZ8uMhwGxsxtOcj4IHjT9tL/AIJ+eHbdNXt5dQ+H2llIIxfrFqmmRoTtjXzUbzoEyQqqWjGSoA6Cv0u/Y4/aatf2sfgraeNYtM/sfUIruTTdSsBJ5iRXMaqx2NwSrJJGwzyN2OcZPudfir+zT/ymR1f/ALHPxZ/6J1GvpL9vb/gnL4y+MnxZPxb+Fes21v4nkS3e7026uGtZTPAqpFPbTjhX2pGMMVwU3BucDwuz/bu/aq/Y68TaTonxr0B9e0qbISLW4I0nniQqH+z3sHyyMMjJfzMbhnqDX64+DPFdj498H6F4m0tmfTNZsINRtWkGGMM0ayISPXaw4rJ+LnxN0H4NfDXxD408TyNHoejWrXFyI1DvJyFWNQSAWdmVACQCWGSOtfnx8Jf2sfj5+0SPENx+zl8E/Bvgvwy18Y77W9QKAm52LhnKmJXl2FCQI5CoKgnkZ+bf2I7fXrL/AIKmafbeKLq1vPE8WveIo9VubFQsE12LS+EzxgKoCGQMQAqjGOB0rT/ay0a08R/8FdIdJv4EubC/8VeF7W4hkXcskb29grKR3BBIxX1h/wAFq7OB/wBmfwjdtGpuIvF9vEkhHKo1leFh9CUU/gK9d/4JdsX/AGFfhmScn/iZDn0Gp3Yr6qoooooor8Pf+CxMsz/tZwJJPDJEmgWvlRRnLRgvKTv44JOffG32r4ZrvvgBY3WqfHP4f2VlejTrq516ygS7ZyghLTou4sCCAM9iPqK/pktLmG8tYZ7eZLiCVA8csTBldSMhgRwQR3qaiiiiiiivzA/4Jg/sZ/GL9nf4+a/4j+IPg/8A4R/RrrwzcafDc/2nZ3O+drq1kVNsMzsMrE5yQB8uM5Iz9+/tCeFtU8cfAP4l+G9Etvtutax4Z1PT7G18xY/NuJbWSONNzkKuWZRliAM8kDmvkH/glN+y78Tv2bP+Fo/8LH8M/wDCOf21/Zf2D/T7W687yftfmf6iV9uPNj+9jO7jODjgPjf+xp8YfGH/AAUs074q6R4P+1+AYfE3h7UH1b+07NMQW0dks7+U0wl+UwycbMnbwDkZP+Cn37Gnxi/aI+Pmg+I/h94P/wCEg0a18M2+nzXP9p2dtsuFurqRk2zTIxwsqHIBHzYzkHHv/wDwUG/Y98XftOeGtNvPA3i660bXdNjaGTRbm/mh07UoSc/Mq5VZVOcMVIYHaxAAI+PPFX7NH7e3xj8H23w18Y3nm+DEaJGbUdV03ynEZBQyyQlriUKVVsOGOVBwSBX6J/sefs1Wn7KfwS07wTDfjVNReeTUNTvkUqk11IFDFFPRVVEQZ5ITJwSQPcK/MD4H/safGHwf/wAFLNS+Kur+D/sngGbxN4h1BNW/tOzfMFzHerA/lLMZfmM0fGzI3cgYOOh/bE/Yf+OOp/HGP4sfBbxpf392LgXsWjX2sNHLptxja32YzN5RhYFsxsVADFQCpwPIdV/YY/a3/a58caFN8dtYt9J0nTMxi7u7qykaCFiDJ5FvZZQyNtXltudq5bgCv1k8JeF7DwT4U0bw7pUTQ6XpFlDp9pExyUhijCIue+FUDNcR+0t8F4v2h/gX4v8Ah5Nef2d/bVqqQ3ZXcIp45EliZgOqiSNCR1IzX5kfBr9jv9t/4GXer+DvA2q2vhXw1q0+bvVItUs5bMnAXz0DBp422gDckauQq+gx0P7Pn7Afxn/Z1/bg8MeLBokni/wZpt64ufFJ1C0iadLm0eKacwvP53yvO5IwWOw43ZBPTfG/9jT4w+MP+ClmnfFXSPB/2vwDD4m8Pag+rf2nZpiC2jslnfymmEvymGTjZk7eAcjPv/8AwU++Avjv9oj4B6B4c+Huhf8ACQa1a+JrfUJrb7XBbbIFtbqNn3TOinDSoMAk/NnGAcd/+wX8LfE/wY/ZP8DeDfGWmf2N4k0z7d9rsvtEU/l+Zf3EqfPEzIcpIh4Y4zg4IIH0DRRRRRSGv58P+CjHjnV/H/7WnjW81PSptJg0+caTZRTw7GeCAbQ5OPmLEl/UBwO1fM9AJU5BIPtX75/8EttR8Rav+xz4VvPEN3Ldh57mLTmlfcVtI5DEijjgAxvgHP8AQfWtFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFfhx/wAFhZZZP2uFVxII49BtFjLg7SN8pO32yT+Oa+HqK/f3/gmL4V8T+FP2O/B8XieRla8M19p1qyBTbWUjbolOOu75pcnnEor6rooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooor8Ov8AgsOf+MtkHk+Wf7AtP3hl3GT55eQuflA6Y7kE96+HK9d/ZR/Z/wBS/aX+OPh7wTYq6Wc0n2nVLpeltZRkGWQnsSCEX/adR3r+j7RdHtPD2j2Ol2ECW1jZQJbW8MYwscaKFVQPQAAVdooooooooooooooooooooqjq2r2OgaVe6nqd7b6dptlC9zc3l3KsUMESAs8kjsQFVVBJJwAASawPAvxY8EfFA3v/AAhvjHw/4tFjs+1/2FqkF79n37tnmeU7bN2x8Zxna2OhrraKKKKKKKKKK/HT/gr/APBbxrqfx1sfGeneFru98My6TbWh1KxtmkX7QJHXZIVB+Y7lCjuBwODX5xV+pv8AwRIg0Jbr4izNZM3iOQW6JePECq2y5JRH/hJZssO+E67Rj9W6KKKKKKKK8Z/aK/a2+Gv7Lml2tz451p4L29Baz0mxi8+8uADyyxggKvbc5Vc8ZzxXkfwg/wCCqPwL+L3iq18Pre6z4Sv7yQQ2reJrSOCGaQnAXzYpZFQnsXKgnjOSM+1/tH/tEaL+zF8PD428RaFr2taJHcx2tw2gQQzPbb8hJJBLLGAhbauQT8zqMc5rmPCX7bPw08X/ALNuq/G23ur208J6WJlu7S7ijW+hnRgotyiyFPNctHsG/B81MkZOLP7LX7XXhn9rbRtb1fwl4d8TaVpOlTpbPfa9bQQxTzEbjHEYp5CzKpUtkAAOvJzXC/Hb/gph8FfgH4vvfC+p3ureI9dsH8q9tPDtok4tZB1jeSSSNNw6EKxKng4IIrR/Z4/4KJ/B39pPxTF4Z8P3+p6L4knVmttM1+1WCS5CgswjZHdCwAJ27txAJAIBxp/HH9uj4d/s9fGnwt8NPFlrrMeqeIIbW4i1SCK3Gn2sc9zJbh55ZJkZFVomZyFIC88nIHl3iH/gr78AdC8SvpVvN4k1q2STy21fTtMU2g5wW/eSJIR3yEOR0zXonxV/4KJfA/4T+CvD3iW58Tt4gg1+2+16bY6DF591PDuKl2RigjAZWUiQqdysMEqwG1+zN+238MP2rJb+z8HX97a63YxfaJ9G1i3EF0IchfNUKzI65KglWOCVzjIzS+OP7c/w9/Z8+NPhb4a+K7TWo9V8Qw2txFqlvFb/ANn2sc9zJbq88kkyMiq0TMxCEBeRk5A8t1P/AIK/fADTvFLaTHL4lv7JZPLOtWulqbTGfvYaRZSv0jz7V7X8e/GuhfEX9i/4o+JfDOqW+taDqXgfWJ7S+tW3JKv2Kb8QQQQQcEEEEAgivh3/AIIY/wDNbP8AuCf+39fWH7QP/BR/4M/s6+KJ/Des6hqXiHxDanbd6d4dtkuHtG/uyO8iRhvVAxYdwK6D9nD9uj4T/tRX0umeEdWubPxBFGZm0PWYBb3TRjqyAMySAdwjEgckAV9CUUUUUUUUV55+0NfvpvwL8f3Ed5bae8ehXrC7vP8AVQ4gfLt64GTjv071/M1X6y/8EWPizearpni/4ey2Wlw2WlRLqMN1GqpeTGSQhg2BmRV/vE/LlR34/UOiiiiiiiivwN/aK+KfhrxT/wAFD/FmufFqz1TXfBOieI7jTLnS9NCtNJa2ZeGKGNWdAFZ41LDcuQ7kHceU/bU+Nn7OPxm8P6BN8H/hzqfgHxLY3Pl3ZbS7SxtLm0KN95YJ33Sq4TBKgkM+WOAK/Vf9kq6t/wBp39g/wda+NUbWLbXNDm0bUTMcvOsMstqZCx/jxCG3dd3PWvxQ8eaFr/w08eeLPgbF4wt5PDSeJ0guJvtAWxlnhd4YrmQjOzasjbx2I5BKDH9A3wC+Dehfs/fCHw54H8P7WsNLtgHu9oDXUzfNLO3u7lm68AgDgCvzm1rxl+w18C/ix4hvNM8Oax8ZPEd/I0L6YLVdasYpy7M7RNdYEjMTy4aXgfKRls/LnhXXLC5/4KK+BdS8PeBrv4X6bd+NNEaHwvdIY5LKOWW3DfKVXasgdpAoAAWUAZABPrH/AAWq/wCTp/C3/YmWn/pdfV9Gftz/ALGvwq+Df7Ber3GgeD9Ls/EXhpdNZNeS3UX1xK93BBK0s333DCVztJKg4wBgY4H/AIJGfsu/Dv4n/DDxj438aeFtM8W3v9sNotrDrFstzDbRxwRSuyRuCu5jcKNxGRsGCMnPkP7F+h2/w5/4KtSeFdFDW2kaf4g8SaRFCGJ/0eGC9EaknrjykPOeRWh/wWq/5Ol8Lf8AYmWn/pdfV9e/tGfsC/CHwn+xX4otNJ8J6ZZ+IPC3h2XVYPEkMCi/nuLaEyu0k33nWTYwKsSoD/KBhcfM/wDwT28cajqv7C37VvhS4meXTtG8OXt7aK5yI2udOu1kVfQZtlOOmWY9zUf/AASd8X3Pw9+Df7VHimyAa80PQbPU4ARkGSG31OReO/KjivnH9j/4v/Bn4d/EDxF4q+OnhPVviJcXEYOn26WdvfQmd3Zp5rhLiZA7fd253DLOSAQDSfE/46fDnRv2qfD/AMT/AIFaHqvgvRLGe0v5NLvYIrcR3KOfOSNIpZFELxhQVyBl3G0Liv6F6KKKKKKKK+Kv+CuGpahY/si6lHaavFpdpcalaw3cRBMt6hfKwJjAHzKHYk/diIwc1+FlfVP/AATJ+INv8Pv2wvBst/qMmn6dqXn6dMFJ2StLEyxK4HGPMKHJ4GM9q/f+iiiiiiiivyE/bM+B3xL/AGU/2vx+0J8O9Bn1zQrq/OrtLBbPOlpcSIUuoblU+ZUl3yEPwMS4BDDnpdN/4K+/FL4k63pWk/D74HQX+otIEurRbm51GSY/9MxFHH5XPOW3gD86+iv2zf2xte/Z4/Ze0291bT7Xw38XvFdqbaz0azvBdDTZCv76fzNq7vKVlGQCPMZQCygsfhn4ef8ABMnxJ8Rf2ONU+JzNeN8RNQYaxo2jucm509VYsrDqZpwxkTrkJGOPMbH0Z+wD+0jqf7SH7MHjf4IX2qm1+JGkeHbvTtHvZ5Nrz2skLQwyE9d0DuiMeu3yzydxr44/ZQ+PvjP9gT4oeK9K1f4TTa54j1aKOxOnXoe1voHjZ8eS4ikLI5fkKCH2oQ3AzX8ceI/Hlh+3r4A+Inxh0NfB+s6xr+ieI5rCRSgtbFLmOOLcpJKlY7fBDfMCp3AHIHpn/Bav/k6bwt/2Jlr/AOl19X3/AP8ABUf/AJMT+Jv/AHDP/TpaV5V/wRU/5NY8U/8AY53X/pDY18qfs0/8pkdX/wCxz8Wf+idRpf8AgtV/ydP4W/7Ey0/9Lr6tT49/tz/HC1+D93+zz4s+Gk2k+OJrVdEv9aDSyS6hbjCEwwBNrNKowZFdlYMxVRkY9x/Zq/Zh139nf/gnZ8db/wAW2T6Z4o8V+F9VvZtOlGJbS2j0+ZYI5B2f5pHI6qHVSAQRXnP/AARf8NWXjPwt+0J4f1JDJp2rWelWFygPLRSpqKOP++WNeWfD3xF8Xv8AglH8Y/FMGqeC5PEvhPVQtvJcMJIbTUY43YwTw3Kq6xyAO2UYMR5jArnBH058B/8AgpF8b/2i/ilaaZ4Q+B9lN4XuJI0muZbu4CWKZ+eWa92CPAGSFEQY4wAxIFfpDRRRRRRRRX5Tf8FvvE92s/ww8PLfsLBxeX8lgo4aRfLRJGPsGcD/AHn9a/LCprKeS2u4ZYXaOVHDKy5yCDx0r+oXwI93J4I8Pvfm4N82n25nN3t84yeWu7ft43ZznHGa3aKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/Iv/AIK5/BH4i/En9pDw3qfhHwD4o8VabF4TtraS80XRrm8hSUXl4xjLxIwDAOp2k5wwPcV+ulFFFFFFFFFFFFFfkh/wW/lUeM/hdEIogxsb1jLt+dgHiwpPoMk49zX5jU6NtkisOCCDxX9Pvwruftvww8I3G1083SLSTbI7OwzCh5ZvmJ9zye9dTRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRX5H/8ABb+3gHjT4Xz+YftTWF6hjwcbBJEc56dSenpz2r8x6ktwpuIg4JTcNwHUjNf1E+CI4YfBmgx2+nvpNuthAsdhJjdbKI1xGccZUccelbdFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFfmR/wWq+E1zq3hLwb8RU1S1htNGlbSZNPmJWWV5zvVo+DuOImJBxgKTz2/I6rGmwfadRtYd2zzJUTd6ZIGa/qQ8P6XHoeg6bp0Ukk0VpbR26STOXdgqhQWY8knHJNaFFFFFFFFFFfmB/wU++FXwe8cfH3Qb/AOIXxz/4VlrUfhm3gh0j/hEbzVvNgF1dFZ/NhYKuWZ12EZHl56MK+6Pjn+1F8Mf2bP7E/wCFj+Jv+Ec/trz/ALB/oF1ded5Pl+Z/qIn2482P72M7uM4OOe+JH7c/wJ+EviWXw/4n+JGmWesQuY5rS1imvGgcdVkMEbiNh3DEEV1ur/tIfC/Qfhlb/EO/8c6ND4MueLfV1ug8U7c/JGFyzvw2UUFhtbI4OM34NftY/CT9oC/uLDwF43sNe1C3QyPY+XLbXGwHBcRTIjsoyOQCBkc8iuy+I/xR8JfCHw3L4g8Z+ILDw3o8bBPtV/KEDOeQiDq7EA4VQScHjivFNC/4KP8A7N/iLV4tNtPijYRXMjbFe9sru0hz7zSwrGB7lgK+j4LmG5t0nhlSWCRRIkqMGVlPIYHuMc59K8C1T9v/APZ70bxcfDV18UtHXVFl8lmjWaS1Vs4wblUMIweCS+BXUWv7Vvwqv/jXD8JLbxZHcfECZBJFpUVlcsjobUXYZbgR+SQYMPkP7deK7nx58QfDXww8NXPiHxZrlj4d0W2wJL3UJ1ijBPRQT95j0CjJJ6A1474I/b//AGffiF4ih0PRfibpsmpTOIoo76C4skkcnAVZJ40RiegAJz2zX0LRRRRRRRRRRRX5c/8ABbuDVZNB+Gtx/attFoaXV1GNL3kTTXJRSZtvQqiALnsZv9qvydqS2V2uYhGCXLgKF65zxiv6iPAtjc6Z4J8P2d5GYru30+3imjaUylXWNQwLnluQfmPXrW5RRRRRRRRRX4rf8Fq/+TpvC3/YmWv/AKXX1eq/8Fzf+aKf9xv/ANx9QaN/wTq+Gaf8E97/AOI+qW19efEK48Hy+Lo9YN7Iqwn7MbqOFYg2wrsCqSwZiSxBHAHjH/BMX9lzw7+1R4j8UQeP5tQ1Xwb4SjiuIdAjvZYYJLu7LL5hKMCo2WpzsKliqZOFwaFx4Asv2Yf+CqXhvwj4MmubLSbLxfo9rbK8xd0tr1bcyQlzyw2XLpzkkdSeSfvv/gof+z18MvixL4T8Q/FD4vy/DvSdI3RQafO8TQ3YLhpjDGcOZmUKu5d20Kp2HnP5x/tnt+yfH4d0W1+AEWqnxFBdhb+7c3hs57by33E/am3+ZvEeNihSC/tX0p4s+N/iDwb/AMEa/Ac9pqE8WpeILmTwt9rVyJEtVu7wFAewMFr5XsrEcdpP2Av+Cc/wu+N/7M0Pjfx5Z32pav4jmuksJrW9kt/7OiileAMiqQruXjdsyBlxtG3g58G/YP8ADN94H/4Ka+G/C+o3r6jeeH9S1rRXuZCSXFrp95AuMk4UCMADoAABwK6z/gqr8U5fiB+2Bp3w71zWpdF8E+GRY29xIqNLHbtcpHNPdmNQS7LFKgwATiPAGSc8t+1V4b/YxX4OJL8EvFd8fH2nSQBbe4t9TYarGWCymQ3EKxxuoJkymwfKw2nIA/Rf/gl18YNV+L/7Jujy63dSX+p+Hr2fQZLuZtzypEsckW49ysU0a5PJ25PJzX1zRRRRRRRRRRX4kf8ABZHxFqmo/tRadpN1cl9L03QoGsrYE7UMskjSvjpuYqoJHUInpXwdT4Jntpo5Y22yRsHVvQg5Ff0UfsL/ABp1v4+fs1eF/FviG3ePVZfNtZrgqFW6MTlPNUZ6cbST1ZWPTFe+0UUUUUUUUV+K3/Bav/k6bwt/2Jlr/wCl19Xqv/Bc3/min/cb/wDcfX1V/wA4sv8AujP/ALg6+Vf+CGP/ADWz/uCf+39eVftLf8pktH/7HPwn/wCitOqn/wAFRJNX8N/t02OueNdIuNc8EJHps+m6fM7Rw3ljEEN1bI4+6WlE4bHI8wHHIzm/tk/tSeCv2g/g3p/hn4P/AAkuPB/gvw7qEGqavqQ023tI4pikkEEWLcsgB858Fm3MRwowTXuPhP4L6j+0X/wR58L6L4ZhOpeI/DmoXmq29hFy80sV/dl4gO7mC4Yqo5J2jvXnv7GX/BTjSP2Y/gNcfDvxV4S1bV9R0ee5k0drFo0jbzHaRobjewaPEjOdyhzhsbRjnzj/AIJ7+IdU8W/8FJPC+u63EYda1PUtcvb6MoUKTyWN68gKnlcMzDB5HSvW/wDgqz8FNc+G/wC0do3xwtdBh8QeFdQaxkvlu7fz7Rby22IILlCCPKljjjGG4b517c29S/4KD/soxeH7KXT/ANlbQ7rXHKfarO50DSobaL+95c4jdnx2zEufav0U/ZO1vw34o+Dthr3hX4X/APCpdI1aZrtNDOnW9j5xKqoufLhwCHCqAzAMyopxt2k+y0UUUUUUUUUV+G3/AAWC1WK+/a2FtGYi1poVokoQfMHYyPhj67WUj2I9a+IKmsrK41K8gtLSCS5uriRYoYIVLPI7HCqoHJJJAAFf0T/sN/A7U/2e/wBmnwn4T1ueSXXBG99fRPIWW3mmbeYV5wAgIU44JDHvXvdFFFFFFFFFcP40+CPw6+JWqxan4u8A+F/FWpRQi2jvNb0a3vJkiDMwjDyoxChnY7Rxlie5q345+E/gj4oGy/4TLwb4f8Wix3/Zf7d0uC9+z79u/wAvzUbZu2JnGM7Vz0Fa3/CJ6H/wi3/CM/2NYf8ACNfYv7N/sf7LH9j+y7PL+z+TjZ5Wz5dmNu3jGOKyfAvwn8EfC83v/CG+DvD/AISF9s+1/wBhaXBZfaNm7Z5nlIu/bvfGc43Njqaqan8Efh3rXjJPF+oeAPC9/wCLEniuV1260a3kvlliCiKQTlC4ZAiBTnK7VxjArZ8X+BPDXxB0wad4p8PaV4l08NvFpq9lHdxBvXZIpGffFZv/AAp7wF/whsvhD/hCPDn/AAiczrJJoX9k2/2F2DBgxg2bCQyqcleCoPYVxnxS+HusfDv4B+K9N+AOjaH4N8VIgvtMs9M0y2gt5p1eNpEMWwRl5Y42i3MOCynIwCPzCtP+Ch+r+Bteu5vi5+zR4S1v4jxT5i1q50pdKvo3AH+tElvK7tnnKsnGB712P/BNP4JePfif+1drv7QHivw/caBpLzajqcU09u8KXd7elwywB+WjVZpiXGQCFGSScfrPe2NvqVpNa3kEV1azKUkhnQOjqeoYHgj2NcLpP7PHwr0DVl1XS/hp4P03U1bet7aaDaRTBvUOsYOffNeh0UUUUUUUUUUV/PR/wUYk8z9s/wCJh+0XF0wvIVZ7lgSMW8WFXA4VRhVHXCivm6v1I/4I+/s3+AvFdjf/ABT1OX+2fF2kX7Wdpp86ARaaQiss4HO92DHaxxtwcDOGr9XwMDFLRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRX88f/BRB7dv2zPicLaIRKt/GHw5Ys/kRliSfcngdOlfOdfr1/wRa06/XwB4svpvDKW1i90IoPEEZKG6IGWhcZw+wkENgkbiMjiv0uooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorz74o/H34e/Bi3jk8a+L9K8NmVGeKK+uVSSUAc7E+8x+gr+e/9qv4qWPxq/aD8beMtLt4bfTdSvi1sIVKiSNVCLIdwB3Pt3HIzlsdq8or379jr9q7X/2X/inpOqR393L4Ukm8vVNKDs8Twuyea6R52iTEa4br8o9MV+5Pwu/a7+EXxg8PS6x4d8c6U1vAoa4ivp1tZbfJwN6SEEZP8xXkv7VH/BSL4d/s96PapolzaeO9fvkMltb6Vexy26qr7W8yVC20jrtxzg815An/AAWt+Hnk2zv4I1sM8kqSok8ZMYUrsboMhgzehBUjuDXmer/8Fttah1a9j0/4eadPYJO628sl3IGeIMdjMMcEjBIqOP8A4Lca6+n6jv8Ah3p0V8IQbP8A0qRo2k3qCJBwduwucg9QPWma/wD8FtdekSWPSPh9YRl7ZAs0905aOYxjfx0IVy2PUAZrrfhF/wAFpdIPhvRrD4g+Ebs6+qLFfappkiC2lbcR5gjPK/LtJAzyWxxgV093/wAFq/h5BbaVJF4J1q4e5hMl3EtxGDaPuYbORh/uqcjHDjuCKyvHP/BanwxB4Rtrrwl4Mu7nXnuykllqswWNIV2EtuTuwZgvoUORivVPBf8AwVw+B/iTTdFbVJtV0DU78lJrOa281bRtxA3yA4wcA5x/EM45qp4i/wCCvvwT0yDR7jTE1fV4Lq7WC9RbfyprKIqT5uxjiQAjBANezaf+3r8A9QtbGYfErSLdru2S6SG4ZkdVYA4YbflYbhlevX0rVH7aHwQbSp9SHxK0JrKCVIZJROTtdgzKMYzyEfH+6ar2n7b/AMCb+3ea3+JuhyokD3LAStuEaqWY7dueFBOMZ4NT6d+2n8DtWvreztPiZoM1zcOI4kFxjcxOAMkY5Nc14t/4KHfATwl4fm1c+PLTVoIbyOykh0tGmmV3yQ2zAJUAEkjPQ4yeK4yX/gqz8AhdXNomt35uopJIV8yzZYndSQDvBI2sQMN6EGvCof8Agtv4cPiVBL8PNQGgtagsy3afaY7jPI6bWTHfg5rbb/gtj8PQhK+BNeLY4BniGTTIP+C2fw/eFGl8Ba9HIQCyC4iYKe4z3q5f/wDBaj4bW9taSW/g/XLqWWEySxeZGhhfcw2Ekc8KrZHZh3Brzj4vf8FppbzQIbf4d+Ejp+pXVkxlu9VkEhsrgsQAqgbXAAzzwQw6HIrx7Uv+CxPxtuLhXs4dCtYvKjVo2sg+ZAih2Bz0LBiB2Bx2qhb/APBX749xR7ZJ9CmbJO9tOUHGeBwe3StDVP8AgsT8bLi5V7KDQ7WHyo1MbWQf94EUOwOehYMQOwIHaup+HH/BaL4h6HZm38X+F9J8SyGcuLy3zayLGf4Nq/KSOx4z39a+lv2a/wDgrp4A+J7xaT8RbRfh/rjMFS7Mhl0+fgnO/G6I8AYbI5Hzen0x8Iv2ufhb8aj4hj8PeJ7aO50G6a2v7bUHW3kjw5QSDccNGzDAYEjp0JFd6/xQ8GxlA3izRFLsEUHUYRuYnAA+bqT2p1x8TPCFpPPBP4q0WGaBHkmjk1CJWjRPvswLcBe5PTvW9ZXtvqVnBd2k8V1azossU8Lh0kQjIZWHBBBBBFT1WvNRtdPi8y5uIrdDwGlcKPzNfDn7Rn/BWP4e/BzxBq/hrw7pl1401q0jKpd2M8QsBPyCjybi3ynrhTX5PftMftKeIf2pPH8Xi3xLpul6bqEdqtoE0uN0VkUkqW3MxLc4zx9K8koooBIB569aKKKKKKKKKKKUOwQoGIUkErngkdP5n86FYqcgkHGOKTpRRRRRRRRRRRRVi11G6sROLa5lgFwnlzeW5XzF3BtrY6jcqnHqB6U1r65YYa4lIznlz1q1ceItUu9Qub+bUbmW9ufM86d5WLyeYCJMnPO4MQfXNfpH/wAEpf24f+EVvrf4L+OdRSPRbl2fw7qV3LtW1lPzNaMzcBH5ZOmHJXneoX9Rvif8VPDHwg8G3vifxXq1vpGj2q5aed8bmP3UUd2PQAda/Ar9sr9rLWv2oPijqOprNdWHheJhDYaULmQxbEJCyPHvKeYQeSoHb61890UUV//Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! did you figure out how to make the image bigger? I get a very small one

Comment: No, sorry :( Isn’t that related to your screen resolution?

Answer (score 2):

You can not send an image from local machine. To display an image inside teams it has to be hosted publicly(Ex: Azure blob storage). You need to use the image URL.
Please take a look into [Message card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#example-connector-message) for send image in a card to connector.

Comment: While this answer could stand to provide more detail, this does seem to be true. One limitation is the 25kb maximum size of Teams message payloads, as discussed here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/display-images-in-adaptive-cards/ba-p/3036435#:~:text=Images%20always%20enricher%20Adaptive%20Cards,the%20size%20of%20card's%20JSON.