# Send image to MS Teams Channel via Webhook url using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-teams

I simply just want to send an image in Python via a webhook url to my MS Teams channel. I already found some posts regarding my question. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086390/ms-teams-trying-to-send-images-present-on-local-machine-to-teams-channel-web) is similar to my question, but I can not find a sample to do it in Python. There are also different opinions about if it is possible to send an image via python to ms teams channel [looking at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71649556/is-there-any-way-to-share-an-image-file-to-ms-teams-channel-using-python) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368169/post-image-to-ms-teams-channel-programatically).

So I tried my best to send an image file to my teams channel.

```
import cv2
import base64
import json
import requests

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('./frame.png')
retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
my_string = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode()
my_string = "data:image/png;base64," + str(my_string)

x = { "@type": "MessageCard", 
     "text": "Test image",
    "sections": [
        {
            "images": [
                {
                    "image": my_string
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

y = json.dumps(x)


webhook = "<my-webhook-url>"

z = requests.post(webhook, json=y)
print(z)

requests.post(
                        webhook,
                        json={"text": "test"},
                    )
```

However, I always get a <Response [400]> as a result for z. So my image is not posted in my channel. I checked my webhook with the second requests.post with the test message and this one came through.

Just my image is not posted in my teams channel. Does anybody know where I am making a mistake? Maybe some of you has a better solution to do so?

########################################################################
**Update**

I found another way to create the payload for ms teams. Here is my code now:

```
import requests
from base64 import b64encode

webhook_url = '<webhook-url>'
with open('./frame.png', 'rb') as f:
    img_data = f.read()
message = 'This is an image message.'

payload = {
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "0072C6",
    "summary": message,
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": message,
            "activityImage": "data:image/png;base64," + str(b64encode(img_data).decode()),
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(webhook_url, json=payload)
print(response)

requests.post(webhook_url, json={"text": "test"})
```

Now I do get a response of 200, which means that my image was sent successfully. Regrettably, I still can't see the image in my channel.

Does anybody know, why it was sent successfully but I still can't see it? Do I need to have special settings in my ms teams channel for it?

Comment: Could you please try once to send the same payload as mentioned above with the same image path, through postman and check if the image is displaying or not?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-connectors#send-the-message